# Error when adding a new member to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

(I checked out at least a couple dozen posts on SO about this error and made a few changes as I see fit to no avail)

So, I started out with a simple `var`:

```
var _jsonStr = '{"hotspots:":[]}';
```

Then, parsed it:

```
var _jsonObj = JSON.parse(_jsonStr);
```

In other part of my HTML, I get values for variable `id`, `x`, and `y` and assign those values to `_jsonObj` as follows:

```
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].id = id;   // error!
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].xval = x;
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].yval = y;
```

And I'd like to eventually end up with a set of those `id`, `x`, `y` value pairs in my JSON that would look something like:

```
var _jsonObj = {
    "hotspots": [
        { id: 0, xval: 25, yval: 50 },
        { id: 1, xval: 80, yval: 120 },
        { id: 2, xval: 39, yval: 91 },
        ...
    ]
};
```

Hate to admit it but I just couldn't figure out why I keep getting an error that says, *"Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference"* as commented above. It sounds to me like I am doing something wrong with adding a new member to the JSON object but I just don't see why it is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `_jsonObj.hotspots[0]` is `undefined`.

This should fix it:

```
_jsonObj.hotspots[0] = {};
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].id = id;  
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].xval = x;
_jsonObj.hotspots[0].yval = y;
```

Answer (score 3):

`_jsonObj.hotspots[0]` is `undefined`, because `_jsonObj.hotspots` is empty. If you wanted to create a new object with those contents at the end, it would be:

```
_jsonObj.hotspots.push({
    id: id,
    xval: x,
    yval: y
});
```

Small side note: it’s not a “JSON object”, and you’re not “convert[ing] it to JSON notation”. You’re converting it *from* JSON (which stands for JavaScript Object Notation – don’t add another “notation” to the end!) into a *JavaScript* object.

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion that I wasn't using the right terminology. :)